# Simplification in z3 for implication

Tags: z3

Is it possible to use z3 to simplify this expression

[image]

to this one

[image]

? If yes how should we achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

The two expressions are not equivalent. In particular the first formula implies that t_FC < 1.
You can use a tactic called ctx-solver-simplify to simplify formulas like yours to take advantage of context constraints such as t_FC < 1.

An encoding of your example is on: http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/xCN2

```
 tFb, tFc, tFt = Reals('tFb tFc tFt')

 g = Goal()
 g.add(And([Not(tFb >= 1),
   Implies(tFb <= 1, tFb + tFc <= 5),
   Implies(tFb <= 1, tFb + tFc + tFt <= 5),
   Implies(tFb <= 1, tFb + tFc + tFt <= 5),
   ]))

 print g
 print Tactic('ctx-solver-simplify')(g)
```

The result is:

```
¬(tFb ≥ 1), tFb + tFc ≤ 5, tFb ≤ 1 ⇒ tFb + tFc + tFt ≤ 5
```

The tutorial http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/tutorial/strategies explains using strategies from Z3 (in the context of the python interface)

Comment: Hi, sorry for the typo, I have updated the question, is it possible to get the result as given in the question?